# How to design own checkout.js similar to paypal or stripe

Tags: javascript, paypal, checkout

[Paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/add-paypal-button/) and [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration) provides their own checkout.js. Client app/website integrates the checkout.js in their payment page to enable Paypal/Stripe payment button in their interface.

I want to know, if I had to design a similar checkout.js for a payment gateway, what are the things/components to look at? Is there any guidelines/ best practices available on the internet on this? And, is checkout.js really a efficient solution to enable client apps integrate with your payment solution? If not, is their any alternate / better way?

Comment: Did you ever find a method of creating your own solution that works the way that checkout.js does?

Comment: I did. Eventually I designed something similar for my organization. https://developer.bka.sh/

Answer (score 0):

As is the case any time you decide to blaze your own trail when handling sensitive information like credit card details and passwords- proceed with extreme caution. One simple slip-up or oversight could potentially leak your customer's card details to the "bad guys". In short- don't do it.

If you're still trying to create your own checkout solution after considering the above advice, [Stripe's documentation](https://stripe.com/docs) on how to use and customize their Checkout form is a great place to start.

Anecdotally, I can vouch for the effectiveness and ease-of-use of Stripe's checkout plugin.